# How to make a discord bot respond to a command with different images/responses?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

For example, if a user typed a command like `!minecraft` to the bot, it would respond with one image, and if I did the command again, it would respond with another image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - It is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create something like a list of images/ phrases and pick one of them randomly each time:

```
import random

@bot.command
async def hello(ctx):
    # now create a list of images/ phrases/ ...
    phrase_list = ["Hello!", "Hi!", "Good morning!"]
    phrase = random.choice(phrase_list)
    await ctx.send(phrase)
```

Please ask a more precise question next time ;)